# How can I see all functions in the on-prem functions portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

In the on-prem functions portal you can only see functions you built.

Is there a way for developers to view all functions in the on-prem portal and not just ones they built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we log in on-premises portal with our credential, we need to create our own subscription(as many as you need) to host functions. Each subscription corresponds to one folder in the file share.

We have no access to others' subscriptions so that we can't see their functions. It's by design in both Azure portal and on-premises function portal since it's related to basic safety and private assurance. In Azure portal, we can configure to share our subscription while on-premises function portal has no such settings.

If you have access to the file share folder, you can copy functions in other subscriptions to your `~\site\wwwroot` folder to add them to your subscription. Or if possible, users can log in with the same credential to host all functions in one user's subscription. Otherwise, there seems no way to see others' functions.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. Not being able to see other peoples functions makes it a little difficult to collaborate on a prototype. Any idea if this change after preview?